# Close Modal box after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have setup a modal, I want it to close after 5 seconds.

```
<div id="ex1" class="modal">
  <p><img src="https://stanfeldman.baycrest.org/stan_popup.jpg"></p>
  <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a>
</div>
```

Then I use Javascript, and its not working:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(.modal).close();
}, 5000);
```

Here is the live link http://stanfeldman.baycrest.org

Comment: typo? missing quotes around `$('.modal')` ?

Comment: You are missing quote marks around `.modal`, should be `$(".modal")`. Please consider investing times in learning how the developer tools work.

Comment: You should look at the browser's console; there should appear some JS syntax error there.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your code is a missing quote. but you can use my code below as documentation define.

Update your code

```
setTimeout(function(){
$.modal.close();
}, 5000);
```

Read this: https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal#closing